# ipywidgets: how to organize sliders in two columns

Tags: python-2.7, widget, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, ipywidgets

I am trying to work out how to display the sliders of ipywidgets in two (or more) columns. Does anyone have an example how to do it? My code (in jupyter notebook) now is the following:

```
import matplotlib.pylab as plt
import numpy as np
from ipywidgets import interact,FloatSlider,IntSlider
%matplotlib inline
def plotPP(p,p_LP,Tperiods):
    t=np.linspace(0,Tperiods*(np.pi*2),1000)
    f = plt.figure(figsize=(1.618*6,6))
    p_t = p*(1.0+np.cos(t))
    plt.plot(t,p_t,'b',lw=2.0)
    plt.axhline(p_LP,color='r',lw=2.0)
    plt.xlim([t[0],t[-1]])
    plt.ylim([min(p_LP,np.amin(p_t))-0.1,np.amax(p_t)+0.1])
    plt.ylabel(r'$p$')
    plt.xlabel(r'$t$')

p_s       = FloatSlider(min=0, max=2, step=0.01, value=1.0)
p_LP_s    = FloatSlider(min=0, max=2., step=0.01, value=0.481343)
Tperiods_s= IntSlider(min=1,max=10,value=1)
interact(plotPP,p=p_s,p_LP=p_LP_s,Tperiods=Tperiods_s)
```

And it displays the three sliders one on top of the other:[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a couple You can pull this off depending on what you want to do. They easiest that comes to  mind is by using `interactive` instead of `interact` along with `HBox` and `IPython.display.display`. The only thing about this solution is that you may have to start moving the silders before you see the graph.

```
from IPython.display import display
import matplotlib.pylab as plt
import numpy as np
from ipywidgets import interact,FloatSlider,IntSlider,interactive,HBox
%matplotlib inline
def plotPP(p,p_LP,Tperiods):
    t=np.linspace(0,Tperiods*(np.pi*2),1000)
    f = plt.figure(figsize=(1.618*6,6))
    p_t = p*(1.0+np.cos(t))
    plt.plot(t,p_t,'b',lw=2.0)
    plt.axhline(p_LP,color='r',lw=2.0)
    plt.xlim([t[0],t[-1]])
    plt.ylim([min(p_LP,np.amin(p_t))-0.1,np.amax(p_t)+0.1])
    plt.ylabel(r'$p$')
    plt.xlabel(r'$t$')

p_s       = FloatSlider(min=0, max=2, step=0.01, value=1.0)
p_LP_s    = FloatSlider(min=0, max=2., step=0.01, value=0.481343)
Tperiods_s= IntSlider(min=1,max=10,value=1)

ip = interactive(plotPP,p=p_s,p_LP=p_LP_s,Tperiods=Tperiods_s)
display(HBox(ip.children[:-1]))#Show all controls
display(ip.children[-1])#Show the output
```

Please comment below if this is unclear or doesn't work for you.

Comment: Works perfectly! But I wonder if there is still a way to work with the `interact` method such that there will be no need to use `display`..

Comment: Good to hear. It's possible to do this without using the `display` command ultimately it will be more complicated and would involve the `link` and/or `observe` commands you can read about those [here](http://ipywidgets.readthedocs.io/en/stable/examples/Widget%20Events.html#Linking-traitlets-attributes-in-the-kernel).

Answer (score 3):

There is another way to place sliders horizontally and to **see the graph right away without moving the sliders**.

```
from IPython.display import display
import matplotlib.pylab as plt
import numpy as np
from ipywidgets import FloatSlider, IntSlider, interactive_output, HBox
%matplotlib inline

def plotPP(p,p_LP,Tperiods):
    t=np.linspace(0,Tperiods*(np.pi*2),1000)
    f = plt.figure(figsize=(1.618*6,6))
    p_t = p*(1.0+np.cos(t))
    plt.plot(t,p_t,'b',lw=2.0)
    plt.axhline(p_LP,color='r',lw=2.0)
    plt.xlim([t[0],t[-1]])
    plt.ylim([min(p_LP,np.amin(p_t))-0.1,np.amax(p_t)+0.1])
    plt.ylabel(r'$p$')
    plt.xlabel(r'$t$')

p_s       = FloatSlider(min=0, max=2, step=0.01, value=1.0)
p_LP_s    = FloatSlider(min=0, max=2., step=0.01, value=0.481343)
Tperiods_s= IntSlider(min=1,max=10,value=1)
```

The difference is here:

```
out = interactive_output(plotPP, {'p': p_s, 'p_LP': p_LP_s})
display(HBox([p_s, p_LP_s]), out)
```

Comment: Great solution! How would you print the label with the slider?

Comment: @thad If you haven't found the solution yet, you can add a `description` argument when declaring the Slider. For e.g `FloatSlider(descrition='p_s', min=0, max=2, step=0.01, value=1.0)` will show `p_s` as the label for the slider.